# 'Undefined' Notice while populating arrays

Tags: php, arrays

While populating an array with data from a SimpleXML call, PHP throws exception to what it believes as 'Undefined' keys, however, the output is actually correct.

```
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($http_result, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$result = array();

$x = 0;

foreach($doc->users->user as $item) {
    $result['user'][$x]['id'] .= $item->id;
    $result['user'][$x]['name'] .= $item->name;
    $result['user'][$x]['email'] .= $item->email;
    $x++;
}

print json_encode($result);
```

This actually outputs what I expect, i.e. `{"user":[{"id":"4843977","name":"Test New User","email":"test@newuser.com"}]}`

However, the following errors are also present, and I'm not totally sure why - this doesn't appear in 5.2.6 but does for 5.2.10

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: name in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: name in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: name in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 38
```

Answer (score 3):

I think You must change just ".=" to "=" in lines:

```
$result['user'][$x]['id'] = $item->id;
$result['user'][$x]['name'] = $item->name;
$result['user'][$x]['email'] = $item->email;
```

Comment: That'll get rid of most of the errors, but won't get rid of `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/vhosts/sys-dev/docs/file.php on line 36`.

Comment: Maybe try it in loop (without $X): 
    $result['user'][] = 
    array( 'id' => $item->id, 'name' => $item->name, 'email' => $item->email );

Comment: This ends up outputting `{"user":[{"id":{"0":"4843977"},"name":{"0":"Test New User"},"email":{"0":"test@newuser.com"}}]}` which is usable. Although I can see and understand why .= probably shouldn't be used, it was the only way I could get readable JSON output.

Comment: ".=" or "=" doesn't read the JSON output, it just assign value to the var on the left. Now You don't have yet $result['user'][$x]['id'] index then must create it with "=".

Answer (score 3):

You don't define what are $result['user'] and $result['user'][$x].
You need to instantiate them as array so you won't get that error.

```
$result['user'] = array();
foreach($doc->users->user as $item) {
    $result['user'][$x] = array();
    $x++;
}
```

For the undefined indexes in the fields, the problem is similar. You use ".=" when the variable doesn't exists yet. So you should instantiate it first with an empty string.

```
$result['user'][$x]['name'] = '';
```

Comment: The initialization of the arrays is not necessary. Even the multi-dimensional attributes are initialized the moment they are filled for the first time

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the `$result` array first:

```
$result = array('user' => array());
```

And since you’re using the string concatenation and assignment operator `.=`, that would also apply to the `$result['user'][$x]` arrays:

```
foreach($doc->users->user as $item) {
    $result['user'][$x] = array(
        'id'    => null,
        'name'  => null,
        'email' => null
    );
    $result['user'][$x]['id'] .= $item->id;
    $result['user'][$x]['name'] .= $item->name;
    $result['user'][$x]['email'] .= $item->email;
    $x++;
}
```

But that’s not necessary since you can also write it like this:

```
$result = array('user' => array());
foreach($doc->users->user as $item) {
    $result['user'][] = array(
        'id'    => $item->id,
        'name'  => $item->name,
        'email' => $item->email
    );
}
```

---

**Edit**    Since we elaborated that the attributes of `$item` are [*SimpleXMLElement*](http://php.net/simplexmlelement) objects too, `$item->attr[0]` is required to address the string value itself. Thus:

```
$result = array('user' => array());
foreach($doc->users->user as $item) {
    $result['user'][] = array(
        'id'    => $item->id[0],
        'name'  => $item->name[0],
        'email' => $item->email[0]
    );
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it was voted down. Anyway, this solution works, but yields the same results as all other answers so far: `{"user":[{"id":{"0":"4843977"},"name":{"0":"Test New User"},"email":{"0":"test@newuser.com"}}]}` which isn't really valid JSON output

Comment: @jakeisonline: The item attributes like `$item->id` are probably not strings but some other objects instead. So try something like `$item->id[0]`.

Comment: @gumbo: you're right, it's adding them as an SimpleXMLElement Object. Referring to it using $item->id[0] seems to make no difference, as it still shows as `[id] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 4802022 )` when your print_r the array, which means a further array is being added to the JSON output (or, indeed, any output)

Comment: @gumbo: thanks for revising your answer, much appreciated. However, this still outputs odd data. For example: `Array ( [user] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 4802022 ) [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Dropbox Test User.....` I'm at a loss as to why it's dumping the object reference as opposed to just the string/value.

Comment: @jakeisonline: Did you change the code replacing `$item->attr` with `$item->attr[0]`?

Comment: @jakeisonline: And what does `var_dump($item->id[0])` print out?

Comment: It'll print out something like `object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) { [0]=>  string(7) "4802022" }`

Comment: @jakeisonline: Are you really using `var_dump($item->id[0])` and not just `var_dump($item->id)`?

Comment: @gumbo: cross my heart and hope to die really!

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because you're not just setting the array values, but you're concatenating to the current value:

```
$result['user'][$x]['id'] .= $item->id;
```

This line means "take the current value of `$result['user'][$x]['id']` and add `$item->id` to it". The notice is then thrown, because the current value is not yet existent.

Amend the code to this

```
$result['user'][$x]['id'] = $item->id;
```

and you should be safe. No idea though, why 5.2.6 is not throwing the errors, maybe you should check with the error_reporting setting in the php.ini.